# How do I make my eclipse project a M2e Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I get the following error message while adding m2e Maven with eclipse:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for
>   Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.6.1.20150625-2338
>   (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.6.1.20150625-2338)   Missing
>   requirement: Maven POM XML Editor 1.6.1.20150625-2338
>   (org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml 1.6.1.20150625-2338) requires 'bundle
>   com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found   Cannot
>   satisfy dependency:
>       From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
>   1.6.1.20150625-2338)
>       To: org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml [1.6.1.20150625-2338]

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: "_requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found_" Where is  com.google.guava?

Answer (score 0):

First check whether you have maven eclipse plugin installed in your eclipse.

For newer version of eclipse use below update site,
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

For older version of eclipse, for example Indigo use below update site,
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to check the combitability of the plugin and eclipse, as Mars was released a few weeks ago.

Comment: Ah, okay. Because all my PC's updated it automatically.